# Blazor Windows Authentication/Kestrl - accessing the site remotely needs to enter the Windows login again?

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-core, blazor, kestrel-http-server

I created a Blazor application with Windows authentication and hosting with Kestrel/Negotiate following the steps. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel)

It still doesn't work with Windows Authentication until the answer from this question is applied.

1. Add this in the `Configure` method:

```
    app.UseMiddleware<ValidateAuthentication>();

    internal class ValidateAuthentication : IMiddleware
    {
      public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
      {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            await next(context);
        else
            await context.ChallengeAsync();
      }
    }
```

2. And in ConfigureServices :

```
 services.AddSingleton<ValidateAuthentication>();
```

Then I published it as a self-contained application and launched the application `MyApp.exe`.

On the same machine, the browser can access the site without any problem. It shows my Windows account name on the top right corner.

However, when I access the site from the browser on another Windows PC. It will popup a dialog for entering the account when opening the site the first time. The site works after entered the Windows account. Is it a way not to ask for the Windows login?

[image: dialogWindows]

Comment: Do you had any success in making this work?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74896215/windows-authentication-for-blazor-server-app-login-popup  -- basically the same question although I didn't come across it when reseraching before mosting my question

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Edge will use IE's user authentication setting to send the current login in user to login in the windows auth.

If you want to avoid login again, I suggest you could  enable the IE user authentication automatic logon with current username and password setting.

I suggest you could try to follow below steps to modify the setting and try again.

1.Open the IE and find the internet options.

[image]

2.Modify the user authentication mode to **automatic logon with current username and password**

[image]

3.Close the ie and edge and try again.

Comment: The settings are not available on my company computers. BTW, how about Chrome or Edge?