# Windows Authentication for Blazor Server app - login popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, windows-authentication

I am building a Blazor Server app using .NET 6.0.11 and deploying using Http.Sys . The server and clients are all on the same Windows domain. I'd like to authorize users based on their domain login, instead of building a username/password database and infrastructure specific to this app.

The code in `Program.cs` to enable Windows Authentication, based on code from the official documentation:

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    builder.WebHost.UseHttpSys(options =>
    {
        options.Authentication.Schemes =
            AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;            
        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
    });
}

// ...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I view the authentication state using the first code sample from [ASP.NET Core Blazor authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

If I launch the application on `http://localhost:55555` then the page loads instantly and it shows my domain and username successfully.

However, if I launch the application as `http://mycomputername.our.domain:55555`, and access it via Chrome or Edge on the same machine, then a popup appears asking for username and password:

[image: Sign-in popup]

*Note: I had to run a `netsh http add urlacl url=....` one time only; the command was suggested by an exception message generated on first run after changing the launch URL.*

Entering my domain login username and password is accepted, and the previous code sample does show my username successfully. I also noticed the following behaviour:

- setting `AllowAnonymous = true;` means it will not prompt at all for the username/password; the page just proceeds with the user not authenticated.
- If the username/password is not entered correctly (for a user on the domain) then HTTP error 401 is generated instantly, it never tries to execute the Blazor default error page for example.
- I hope the authentication is being done between the client and the domain controller, not sending the user's password over the HTTP connection!

I am presuming the above behaviour will be the same for other domain uses on different machines accessing this server, although have not tested that yet.

My questions:

- is it possible to skip the username/password popup , and just get the domain user that is already logged in on the client machine and doing the access?
- (If not) would deploying to IIS instead of Http.Sys change anything?

There seem to be Blazor-based solutions discussed on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840986/blazor-redirect-to-login-if-user-is-not-authenticated) , but I can't see how to use them because the popup always appears as soon as any page is attempted , before any page is rendered; and if login fails, HTTP 401 error is generated with none of the Blazor pages being executed.

---

*Footnote: I was using HTTP.sys instead of Kestrel due to documentation indicating that Kestrel did not support Windows Authentication; however it is working using Kestrel for me now, along with the information from the Accepted answer -- not sure what the story is there.*

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like going over http?  Have you tried installing a cert and using https?

Comment: Also does it work from connections outside the local machine?  I wonder if the registry change "BackConnectionHostNames" suggested here might help?    https://serverfault.com/questions/722722/windows-auth-in-iis-does-not-work-when-browsing-to-the-website-on-the-server-run

Comment: @scotru yes - have tried HTTPS with self-signed certificate installed as trusted on the browser; and the behaviour was the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a client-side issue.

> If I launch the application on http://localhost:55555 then the page loads instantly and it shows my domain and username successfully.
>
> However, if I launch the application as http://mycomputername.our.domain:55555, and access it via Chrome or Edge on the same machine, then a popup appears asking for username and password:

That's because the browser recognizes `localhost` as a (somewhat trustworthy) server within your intranet, but considers `mycomputername.our.domain` to be a  (potentially hostile) Internet service. For security reasons, Chrome and Edge only use your Windows credentials with servers within your own intranet by default.

To determine which group an URL belongs to, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Edge use Windows's own "Intranet zone" settings. To add your URL,

- search for "Internet options" in the Windows Start Menu, then
- navigate to Security/Local intranet/Sites/Advanced.

If you want to test with a non-Chromium based browser, here's how to configure Firefox. Firefox manages its own list of URLs where Windows authentication is allowed:

- [How to configure Firefox for NTLM SSO (Single-Sign-On)?](https://superuser.com/q/664656/14517)

> I hope the authentication is being done between the client and the domain controller, not sending the user's password over the HTTP connection!

If the client and the server agree to use Kerberos, sure: The client communicates with the domain controller to authenticate and to get a service ticket and then uses that ticket to access your service.

If they don't agree, they will use NTLM. In this case, authentication happens between the client and your server. However, NTLM won't send your password in plain text either, but rather uses it as part of a challenge-response mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, making that change worked perfectly . (Also noticed at the same time that trendmicro.com is listed as an intranet domain, even though we no longer use that product...)

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to skip the username/password popup , and just get the
> domain user that is already logged in on the client machine and doing
> the access?

IMHO, this is not possible with "windows authentication", because the popup dialog that you see is a special browser feature to enable the windows authentication.This one created in order to support internal application with domain authentication. I don't know of any way to access that browser behavior.

> (If not) would deploying to IIS instead of Http.Sys change anything?

Haven't done a deployment with Http.Sys, but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys) it says that Http.Sys supports windows authentication. The deployment would be different since for Http.Sys you need to write the configuration in code, unlike the IIS.